# Mapping Ctrl+s does not work

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I am trying to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save my file however it does not work.

My mappings:

```
map <C-s> :w <CR> :echo "Saved" <CR>
imap <C-s> <Esc> :w <CR> :echo "Saved" <CR> i
```

When in insert mode I see `/:echo "Saved"` in the bottom corner instead of `saved` and when I am in normal mode I see the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

This is at the very top of my vimrc so my other code should not be causing a issue. I am running Vim inside the OSX Terminal.

Comment: Are you using Vim from a terminal? Control+S is also a special keybind picked up by the terminal which means "stop output"... When I try the above 2 keybinds from gVim, it seems to work.

Comment: '`I am also running vim inside the Mac terminal.`' Yes I am running vim via terminal. Would it be better using Alt instead of Ctrl or Cmd?

Comment: [This question has been asked many times](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Vim%20Mapping%20Ctrl%2Bs%20does%20not%20work), by the way ;-) I don't have time to write an answer, but that link should help you...

Comment: To bind save to Cmd-S on OSX you could try mapping from `<D-s>` although I'm not sure if that works in terminal Vim, and it is already a default in MacVim anyway!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To ensure that this workaround runs even when Vim is started by a **separate tool** (such as git), I have this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Allow us to use Ctrl-s and Ctrl-q as keybinds
silent !stty -ixon

" Restore default behaviour when leaving Vim.
autocmd VimLeave * silent !stty ixon
```

This has been working for me on Linux, GVim, Mac OS X and MacVim.

Caveats:

- On Windows, or any other OS lacking the `stty` command, the above will likely throw up errors every time Vim starts!  (`silent!` might mute that.)
- If your shell already had this TTY setting disabled, of course the `VimLeave` autocommand will turn it back on again!  iProgram's approach manages that by detecting the settings at startup.

---

A combination of this and iProgram's solution, which handles compatibility concerns under OS X and Windows, would be great to post up here and/or on the Wiki!

To avoid choosing between `stty -g` and `stty --save`, you could try the following test for just the `ix` option.

```
call system("stty -a | grep '\( \|^\)ixon\>' >/dev/null")
let g:ix_at_startup = (v:shell_error == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Carpetsmoker for the links.

Adding this script into `bash_profile` worked for me.

```
vim()
{
    # osx users, use stty -g
    local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save)"
    stty stop '' -ixoff
    command vim "$@"
    stty "$STTYOPTS"
}
```

Here is a link to it. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files

I also had to remove the space before the :

Answer (score 1):

It should work out of the box if you have these patches:

- [8.2.0852](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0852)  cannot map CTRL-S on some systems
- [8.2.0856](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0856)  CTRL-S stops output

Although, I would rewrite the mappings:

```
nnoremap <c-s> :<c-u>w <bar>echo 'Saved'<cr>
inoremap <c-s> <c-\><c-o>:w <bar>echo 'Saved'<cr>
```