# Ctrl-Key in vim keymaps running on raspbian are not responsive

Tags: key-bindings, linux-debian

I'm currently running raspbian (a 7 version, `cat /etc/debian_version` says `7.8`) on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

Because I have to edit some of my python files directly on the running system, I copied my `.vimrc` file in order to get the vim environment I'm used to work with.

The first thing I noticed is that my self defined keys are not working:

```
map <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
map <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
map <C-n> :tabnew<SPACE>
map <F9> :set number!<CR>
imap <F9> <ESC>:set number!<CR>a
set pastetoggle=<F10>
```

None of these key combinations work, neither Ctrl+n nor F9, etc.

I found this question [Mapping Ctrl+s does not work](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/mapping-ctrls-does-not-work) and I decided to check whether the `stty` settings were the same or not.

```
# on my local debian 7 machine
$ stty 
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?;
iutf8

# on raspbian
$ stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
-brkint
```

they are clearly different, so I tried syncing the settings

```
 # on my local debian 7 machine
 $ stty --save
 6506:5:4bf:8a3....

 # on raspbian
 $ stty 6506:5:4bf:8a3....
```

that didn't help either, adding `silent !stty -ixon` to my `.vimrc` also didn't help.

None of my keymaps seem to be working, I don't understand why.

I also had a strange error with this code:

```
 autocmd BufReadPost *
       \ if ! exists("g:leave_my_cursor_position_alone") |
       \     if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
       \         exe "normal g'\"" |
       \     endif |
       \ endif
```

I've had these lines in my `.vimrc` for ages and now I'm getting this:

```
Error detected while processing /home/teststand/.vimrc-yanez:
line   95: 
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   96: 
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   97: 
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   98: 
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   99: 
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I don't know how to solve these problems. Is the vim build buggy or do I have to change something else in my `stty` settings?

Comment: This looks like, your vim starts in compatible mode. so try putting a `:set nocompatible` into your .vimrc.

Comment: Already tried that (forgot to write that) because I thought this might be it. Sadly it didn't help either.

Comment: perhaps you have a tiny vim installed? What is the output of `:version`

Comment: `vim --version` says: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 Included patches: 1-547`. The `vim-tiny` package was installed though, but the main big package was installed as well. I uninstalled `vim-tiny` but that didn't help either.

Comment: check the version output, which flavor (tiny, big, huge) is running when you start vim

Comment: I don't know how to check the flavor. Executing `:version` I get: http://pastebin.com/JyssupUE  (cannot copy & paste the output in the comment field)

Comment: its a huge version and it expects its vimrc at ~/.vimrc. I am out of ideas now.

Comment: The key mappings: does mapping a simple key (like, say, `n`) work? As for the second error, `:help E10` says "Remove the 'C' flag from the 'cpoptions' option to enable it. Or use :set nonocompatible".

Comment: Only a few mappings. Stuff like `map q :quit<CR>` works, but stuff like `map <S-F12> :qall<CR>` doesn't. The `cpoptions` helped. I wan to build a vim of my own and test it, perhaps some debian maintainer disabled something when building vim.