# How to map a shortcut for saving the file

Tags: key-bindings, save

Can I set something like `ctrl+s` to save the file?

I don't want to use `:w` every time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all stop using `:w` to save. Use `:update` instead. `:update` writes the file to disk only when there are changes. So, it could be really helpful especially if the file is huge.

Now to map `<C-S>` to `:update` here is how you do it

```
nnoremap <C-S> :update<cr>
```

You may also want to have this mapping in Insert mode too. For that use this

```
inoremap <C-S> <Esc>:update<cr>gi
```

This mapping goes normal mode, executes the `:update` command and then leaves you back where you are in `insert` mode.

So, that is how you remap a key.
But I have `:update` mapped to `zz` in my `vimrc` file. `zz` is far more easy to hit than `Ctrl + S`. Also, mapping `Ctrl + S` can cause issues in Unix terminals as pointed out in the comments by @Sato Katsura.

So if you wish to use `zz`, you can add that as follows

```
nnoremap zz :update<cr>
```

Comment: The second mapping does *not* always leave your cursor in the same place! What if you're on the first column? Use `gi` instead of `a`, or better yet, use `<C-o>` instead of `<esc>`.

Comment: Except on the vast majority of UNIX terminals `Ctrl-S` is the stop character.  You can use `stty` to disable it, but then you won't be able to pause a program's output.  Remapping `Ctrl-S` and `Ctrl-Q` is a really bad idea, about as bad as remapping `Esc`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yeah. That's why I don't use `Ctrl - S`. I use `zz` for saving.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thanks for pointing that. I changed `a` to `gi`. But I am not really sure what `<C-o>` does. Can you explain why that is better than `<Esc>` ?

Comment: What I'm saying is, your answer is incomplete without a warning about terminal modes.  It simply won't work on UNIX without `stty` adjustments.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Added that in the answer. Since I have never used a `stty` terminal before I am not aware of these issues.

Comment: `stty` is a command that sets terminal parameters.  It's all explained in the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files).

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop Yes, sure! `<C-o>` is extremely useful for mappings. It means "Leave insert command to do a single normal mode command".

Comment: There's also a question about it btw: [Mapping Ctrl+s does not work](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2419/51)

Comment: @Canux Yeah. `zz` is really easy to hit. It has become a reflex for me these days.

Comment: As others suggested, `<C-o>` leaves the Insert mode (switches to the Normal mode), but after you do one command, it returns back. You might end up at a different position, if you want to (`<C-o>^`), but I don't see a problem with `:update` in this regard. In other words, you might want to do `inoremap <C-s> <C-o>:update<CR>`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's actually set up in the mswin.vim file that distributed with Vim 6.2 and above for windows.

It contains the following mappings:

```
" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
noremap <C-S> :update<CR>
vnoremap <C-S> <C-C>:update<CR>
inoremap <C-S> <C-O>:update<CR>
```

See [Vim Wikia page on mapping Ctrl-S](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files) for this and other possible mappings.

Answer (score 0):

With ideaVim pluging on WebStorm and prettier configured to format on save (not through File Watchers), you must use `:w` instead of `:update`.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for you answer. Since the set of answers are continuously changing it would be good if you could make you answer non depending on other answer. Would it be possible to edit your answer such that it provide a full solution to the original question?