# Why does this command work in gvim but not in (terminal) vim?

Tags: gvim, visual-mode

Here is the command:

```
vnoremap <C-S-S> :s/\v([.!?])\s+/\1\r\r/g<CR>`<i<ESC>
```

The command takes a text selection and divides it into sentences separated by new lines. Why would this work in gvim and not vim?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of either [Can I map a Ctrl + upper-case letter separately from Ctrl + lower-case letter?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4290/51) or [Mapping Ctrl+s does not work](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2419/51).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple modifiers in CLI Vim mappings. Find another mapping.