# Selector for line of text?

Tags: vimrc, cursor-motions, custom-text-object, selection

To grab a full word from anywhere in the word I can do:

- `viw`

And to grab an entire line from start to finish I can do:

- `V`

However, is there a section that grabs all text from the first char to the last? For example, like this:

[image]

I find myself selecting the line of text (from anywhere in the line) quite frequently and it seems like this is a pretty common thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest I can come up with is really `^vg_` to be precise about start and end of line.

But, by way of challenge, perhaps you really need `dd`, `yy`, `cc`, or similar? Even `guu` and `g~~` work.

---

If you can do it with an ex command, `.` is the shortest "this line" range; note that many commands take it by default.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please explain a bit `guu` and `g~~` ?

Comment: Sure; according to `:help gu`, it's an operator that lowercases the following motion. `gU` uppercases, and `g~` toggles case. As with most builtin operators, doubling the sequence operates on the current line (and, since these are length 2, `gugu` and `guu` have been made to work). You might also like `g?` @David542, it's a ROT13

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `il` operator that behaves like `iw` but selects a line, from first to last non-blank character in the line:

```
function! SelectLine(count) abort
  normal! gv
  if visualmode() !=# 'v'
    normal! v
  endif
  let startpos = getpos("'<")
  let endpos = getpos("'>")
  if startpos == endpos
    execute "normal! ^o".a:count."g_"
    return
  endif
  let curpos = getpos('.')
  if curpos == endpos
    normal! g_
    let curpos = getpos('.')
    if curpos == endpos
      execute "normal!" (a:count+1)."g_"
    elseif a:count > 1
      execute "normal!" a:count."g_"
    endif
  else
    normal! ^
    let curpos = getpos('.')
    if curpos == startpos
      execute "normal!" a:count."-"
    elseif a:count > 1
      execute "normal!" (a:count-1)."-"
    endif
  endif
endfunction
xnoremap <silent> il :<C-U>call SelectLine(v:count1)<CR>
onoremap <silent> il :<C-U>execute "normal! ^v".v:count1."g_"<CR>
```

Supports usage in visual mode (e.g.`vil`) or in operator mode (`yil` to yank the line in characterwise mode.)

Supports usage with a count (`v3il` or `y3il`.)

In visual mode, it supports adding to the visual selection with further `il`s adding more lines of text. Works both forward (when the cursor is at the end of the visual selection) or backward (when the cursor is at the start.)

I don't know that this operator is really that useful, considering in many cases you could just as well use a linewise operator or linewise visual mode instead... But I found myself wanting to yank a line in characterwise mode before, and this does it, so here it is if you find it useful.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107467/discussion-on-answer-by-filbranden-selector-for-line-of-text).

Answer (score 1):

You can use plug-in [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) to define custom text objects using patterns or higher level functions.

In fact, vim-textobj-user uses `il` as [an example](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/blob/master/README.md#complex-text-objects-defined-by-functions) of how to use the plug-in:

> ### Complex text objects defined by functions
>
> Define `al` to select the current line, and define `il` to select the current line without indentation:
>
> ```
> call textobj#user#plugin('line', {
> \   '-': {
> \     'select-a-function': 'CurrentLineA',
> \     'select-a': 'al',
> \     'select-i-function': 'CurrentLineI',
> \     'select-i': 'il',
> \   },
> \ })
>
> function! CurrentLineA()
>   normal! 0
>   let head_pos = getpos('.')
>   normal! $
>   let tail_pos = getpos('.')
>   return ['v', head_pos, tail_pos]
> endfunction
>
> function! CurrentLineI()
>   normal! ^
>   let head_pos = getpos('.')
>   normal! g_
>   let tail_pos = getpos('.')
>   let non_blank_char_exists_p = getline('.')[head_pos[2] - 1] !~# '\s'
>   return
>   \ non_blank_char_exists_p
>   \ ? ['v', head_pos, tail_pos]
>   \ : 0
> endfunction
> ```